# how to upload image to own repository using asmx webservice from windows phone 8?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-8, asmx

i am trying to upload an image to my own repository online. I have a webservice in asmx and i am storing path using service. i want to store image in folder that is online. can you please tell me how to upload image from windows phone 8?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: ok. but can you please tell me without service if i just want to store image at http://something.com/dir/ then how can i do that???

Answer (score 1):

WP provides a great infrastructure to upload files to your server using a [BackgroundTransfer Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

The [PhotoUploader](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Photo-Uploader-Background-f3188f5b) from msdn provides a solution including the ServerAPI you need to handle the upload. The Solution might be for WP 7.1 but the ServerSide is fine for WP 8 and above